# laravel 5.4 cartalyst/stripe-laravel and guzzle 6.0 conflict

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, stripe-payments, guzzle

I am creating an application using laravel 5.4 . The application has these following packages

-cartalyst/stripe-laravel": "2.0.*"
-guzzlehttp/guzzle: "5.3.*",

they work fine but now I want to add another package for SMS notification (nexmo package)
"nexmo/laravel": "^1.0" but it requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.0 and stripe only uses guzzle 5.*.*

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Clqr.png]

How do I get these packages to work together ?

Comment: Upgrade your php version then.

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: If you upgraded your php version, you should be able to install `cartalyst/stripe-laravel` version which supporting `guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.0`